# Error when execute cordova plugin remove

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, command-prompt

In command prompt, I am trying to remove a cordova plugin using:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ble-central
```

However, there's an error that says:

```
Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin 'com.internal.plugin.internalstorage'. Please try adding it again.
```

Previously I managed to remove it in another project, and the 'com.internal.plugin.internalstorage' folder does not have any plugin.xml in the first place. Why is it I cannot remove this time?

I already closed all activities that are relevant to the project, but to no avail.

Please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your project got messed up probably, so the cordova CLI is not able to correctly remove the plugin, you will have to do it manually.

Remove your `platforms` and your `plugins` folder. Then open your `config.xml` and delete the entry for the `ble-central` plugin in there, finally open `package.json` and also remove all references of the plugin in there. The add your platform again: `cordova platform add <platform-name>`.